# Installing ffmpg-concat on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ffmpeg, nodejs

I would like to install [ffmpeg-concat](https://github.com/transitive-bullshit/ffmpeg-concat)

on Ubuntu 20.04.

I get this error:

```
(django-con-video) guettli@yoga15:~/django-con-video$ npm install --save ffmpeg-concat
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/guettli/django-con-video/node_modules/gl
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@15.12.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.5 found at "/home/guettli/django-con-video/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.12.0/node-v15.12.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.12.0/node-v15.12.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.12.0/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v15.12.0/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /home/guettli/django-con-video/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/guettli/django-con-video/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/guettli/django-con-video/node_modules/gl/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/guettli/django-con-video/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/guettli/.cache/node-gyp/15.12.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/guettli/.cache/node-gyp/15.12.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/home/guettli/django-con-video/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/guettli/.cache/node-gyp/15.12.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/guettli/django-con-video/node_modules/gl',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! Package x11 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
npm ERR! Perhaps you should add the directory containing `x11.pc'
npm ERR! to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
npm ERR! No package 'x11' found
npm ERR! Package xi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
npm ERR! Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xi.pc'
npm ERR! to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
npm ERR! No package 'xi' found
npm ERR! Package xext was not found in the pkg-config search path.
npm ERR! Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xext.pc'
npm ERR! to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
npm ERR! No package 'xext' found
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'pkg-config --libs-only-L --libs-only-other x11 xi xext' returned exit status 1 while in angle/src/angle.gyp. while loading dependencies of binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/home/guettli/django-con-video/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:369:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.0-72-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/bin/node" "/home/guettli/django-con-video/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/guettli/django-con-video/node_modules/gl
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v15.12.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/guettli/.npm/_logs/2021-05-21T10_11_38_707Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

After installing these libraries it worked:

```
sudo apt install libxt-dev
sudo apt install libxi-dev
sudo apt install libgl-dev
```